# How do I configure Emacs to dedicate the Calculator window?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using emacs 24.3 from emacsformacosx.com on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks). The behavior is the same on emacs 23.4.1 on Debian Wheezy.

I want to automate applying [`set-window-dedicated-p`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html) so switching/opening a buffer won't use certain windows. For example, if I'm in the Calculator and manually use `Meta-:` and enter `(set-window-dedicated-p (get-buffer-window) t)` then it works great - my Calculator window doesn't get hijacked by other buffers. I want it to work like that automatically.

I put this in my `.emacs` file:

```
(add-hook 'calc-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (message "Dedicating %s" (buffer-name))
    (set-window-dedicated-p (get-buffer-window) t)
    (message "Dedication %s" (window-dedicated-p (get-buffer-window "*Calculator*")))))
```

Then I start up emacs, switch to the *Messages* window, and `Meta-x` `calc`. The *Messages* buffer shows

```
Dedicating *Calculator*
Dedication t
```

so I know my hook was called and what buffer it operated on. But the *Calculator* buffer is not dedicated - it doesn't behave properly and `Meta-:` `(window-dedicated-p)` returns `nil`. The *Messages* buffer is dedicated instead.

Why is the *Calculator* window shown as dedicated in the hook but not afterwards? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the `*Calculator*` buffer is not displayed in any window at the point your code runs.

Your 'validation' messages were misleading you. `(buffer-name)` is certainly the buffer you want, but it's not in any window, and so you're actually passing a `nil` argument for the window in all situations. i.e. You're setting the current window dedicated, and then confirming that it's dedicated (which it should indeed be).

I think after advice to `calc` is what you need here. e.g.:

```el
(defadvice calc (after my-dedicated-calc-window)
  "Make the *Calculator* window dedicated."
  (let ((win (get-buffer-window "*Calculator*")))
    (when win
      (set-window-dedicated-p win t))))
(ad-activate 'calc)
```

n.b. I'm not sure exactly how the arguments to `calc` affect the window display, but I think with the test for the window wrapping the call to `set-window-dedicated-p` this code is probably fine in all cases.

Comment: That works nicely at least back to emacs 22.1.1. Thanks!